# Why does a union have to be disjoint to constitute a coproduct?

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

In the wikipedia article of the [coproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct) it says that in the category of sets the a coproduct is a *disjoint* union of sets. It is not obvious to me that the union must be disjoint.

Comment: If it would not be disjoint, you have elements in the intersections which means that they can be either part of one or the other "component" in some element of the coproduct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try taking the coproduct of a set with one element with itself and use ordinary union. Pick two different maps into another set. Do they factor through one map from this potential coproduct, which has one element?

Comment: So the issue is that there is no *unique* $\forall Y \in Sets . f : X_1 \times X_2 \rightarrow Y$ ?

Comment: @fakedrake No, the issue is there is no map at all with the required properties, let alone a unique one, for some $Y$ and choices of maps.

Comment: Wow you are right. Now I am confused as to why disjoint union *is* a working alternative.

Comment: @fakedrake Once you are told that the disjoint union works, it's straightforward to verify that it does by constructing specific maps. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 9):

Matt Samuel has given you why specifically the union fails. Here is why the disjoint union *has* to be the correct notion of "union".

In category theory, when talking about sets, we don't care what elements lie in the set. That's because category theory only talks about objects up to isomorphism. So if we took $A$ and $B$ of the same size, the coproduct *has* to be phrased in a way that doesn't care whether or not $B = A$.

Comment: ... or whether or not $A$ and $B$ intersect

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen In more generality, yes. I just went with my instant "that can't possibly be how it works".

Comment: Came here to write this, saw your answer. +1.

Answer (score 5):

Let us work with just two sets, $X_1$ and $X_2$. Let $X_1 \sqcup X_2 = (X_1 \times \{1\}) \cup (X_2 \times \{2\})$ be their disjoint union, and consider the morphisms $i_j : X_j \to X_1 \sqcup X_2$ given by $i_j (x) = (x,j)$.

Assume the coproduct to be the non-disjoint union, with the morphisms $f_j : X_j \to X_1 \cup X_2$, $f_j(x) = x$.

You know that there exist a unique morphism $f : X_1 \cup X_2 \to X_1 \sqcup X_2$ such that $f \circ f_j = i_j$.

Now, the core of the issue: assume that there exist $x \in X_1 \cap X_2$. Then

$$(x,1) = i_1 (x) = (f \circ f_1) (x) = f (x)$$

and similarly $(x,2) = f(x)$, which shows that $f$ is not well defined.